# ESP8266 doesn't respond to Serial.println("AT")

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

If I don't declare `Serial.begin(115200)`, I can send `AT` commands over serial monitor and it replies me.

[image]

But when I declare `Serial.begin(115200)` and send `AT` commands inside program or serial monitor there is nothing happens.

[image]

Did I miss something?

Comment: Just copy-paste the code/output. Don't post screenshots.

Comment: But I'm not answer to someone. You don't need the codes.

Answer (score 2):

You have connected the tx of the Arduino to the tx of the ESP8266 and the rx of the Arduino to the rx of the ESP8266.

What is happening when you type AT in the Serial Monitor is that you are communicating directly with the ESP8266, and not with the Arduino.

You need to connect the rx of the Arduino to the tx of the ESP8266 and the tx of the Arduino to the rx of the ESP8266.

This has asked and answered a number of times, such as:

[Arduino Uno and ESP8266 serial monitor issue](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/30689/arduino-uno-and-esp8266-serial-monitor-issue/31929#31929)

[Arduino & ESP8266](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/30449/arduino-esp8266?rq=1)

[Arduino Nano v3.0 with ESP8266](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17590/arduino-nano-v3-0-with-esp8266)

[ESP 8266 does not respond at all](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17666/esp-8266-does-not-respond-at-all)

Your ESP8266 definitely uses a baud rate of 115200 (as confirmed by your first screen shot), so you don't need to change that when experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer @Holmez, third link was very helpful.
I was just change the code and the RX, TX pins like below and it works perfect now.
I can send commands to the ESP both in program and over the serial monitor.

[image]

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial wifi(10, 11);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  wifi.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Test");
  wifi.println("AT+CIFSR");
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    wifi.write(Serial.read());
  }
  if (wifi.available()) {
    Serial.write(wifi.read());
  }
}
```